# How to provide a Flux with live time series data starting from a certain time in the past?

Tags: java, spring, time-series, reactive-programming, project-reactor

My goal is to develop a repository that provides a Flux of live time series data starting from a certain time in the past. The repository should provide an API as follows:

```
public interface TimeSeriesRepository {
//returns a Flux with incoming live data without considering past data
public Flux<TimeSeriesData> getLiveData();

//returns a Flux with incoming live data starting at startTime
public Flux<TimeSeriesData> getLiveData(Instant startTime);
}
```

The assumptions and constraints  are:

- the application is using Java 11, Spring Boot 2/Spring 5
- the data is stored in a relational database such as PostreSQL and is timestamped.
- the data is regularly updated with new data from an external actor
- a RabbitMQ broker is available and could be used (if appropriate)
- should not include components that require a Zookeeper cluster or similar e.g. event logs such as Apache Kafka or Apache Pulsar or Stream Processing Engines such as Apache Storm or Apache Flink because it is not a large-scale cloud application but should run on a regular PC (e.g. with 8GB RAM)

My first idea was that I would use Debezium to forward incoming data to RabbitMQ and use Reactor RabbitMQ to create a Flux. Actually this was my initial plan before I understood that the second method in the repository that considers historical data is also required. However, this solution would not provide historical data.

Thus, I considered using an event log such as Kafka, so I could replay data from the past but found out the operational overhead is too high. So I dismissed this idea and did not even bother to figure out the details on how this could have worked or potential drawbacks.

Now, I have considered using Spring Data R2DBC but I could not figure out how a query should look like that fulfills my goal.

How could I implement the Interface using any of the mentioned tools or maybe even with plain Java/Spring Data?

I will accept any answer that seems like a feasible approach.

Comment: In fact, you have 2 questions:
 1) how to read  live data starting at some startTime using Debezium, in any format/interface/approach
 2) when you find out that interface, then the second question arise: how to convert it to Flux.
I doubt you'll find someone who is able answer both these questions.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Sorry, that this question may not be well-scoped enough. Maybe I should have split these questions, now that you mention it. Now, I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: yes I mean you should ask 2 separate questions.